# Bokeh DataRange1d slowly moves off of the screen

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a Bokeh plot with a DataRange1d with `follow='end'`.  I find that, over time, the contents of this plot slowly shift off the screen towards the left.

Answer (score 6):

In [this gitter chat](https://gitter.im/bokeh/bokeh?at=56f559b18d2a72471b7a3489) it was suggested to set `range_padding` to zero, especially if the magnitude of the data continues to increase.

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d

```
x_range=DataRange1d(follow='end', follow_interval=10000, range_padding=0)
```